# SQL SERVER INSERT STATEMENT WITH LOOP Needs Optimized

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have SQL Statement running in SQL server 2014. 
I have 3 columns: id, text1, text2 
Inserting records in text1, text2
text1 is nvarchar
text2 is  varchar
so far inserted 1.2 million rows in about 3.5 hrs
trying to insert 3 million need help in reduce time for insert

CODE:

```
DECLARE @i as int  
SET @i  = 0 

WHILE  @i < 3000000
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1
    insert into test (text1 , text2)
    values(N'你好','VJ'+ cast(@i as varchar(20)))
END
```

Comment: try inserting in batch rather. like 1M per batch

Comment: Why not use bulk insert? Why are you using a loop?

Comment: @vj78 check my Answer is helpful

Comment: Forget looping for this. It will be slower than watching paint dry. You should use a tally table for this. Even with 3 million rows this would take maybe 15-20 minutes as a single insert. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Comment: I tried @Rahul approach for batch, it took 6 min for 3 hundred thousand records. I tried a batch of 10

Comment: @George Stocker - I am not really sure how to do a bulk insert all examples are showing me bulk insert via a file but I need to create this incremental column, nvarchar, 'vj' + incrementalcolumn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to do it ... It finish pretty fast ... less then 5 sec on my SQL server

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Numbers') is not null drop table #Numbers
create table #Numbers (Num int)

insert into #Numbers (Num)
SELECT TOP (3000000) n = CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]))
FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

if object_id('tempdb..#test') is not null drop table #test
create table #test (text1 nvarchar(50), text2 nvarchar(50))

insert into #test (text1, text2)
select N'你好' [text1], 'VJ' + cast(Num as nvarchar) [text2] from #Numbers
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it comes to be fastest 50 million rows in about 30 sec on my system.

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it comes to be fastest **5 million** rows in about 30 sec on my system.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
WITH CTE_TEST
AS
(
    SELECT N'你好' AS CODE,'VJ'+ cast(1 as varchar(20)) NAME, 1 AS VCOUNT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N'你好' ,'VJ'+ cast(VCOUNT+1 as varchar(20)) NAME, VCOUNT+1 AS VCOUNT
    FROM    CTE_TEST
    WHERE   VCOUNT+1 < 3000000
)
INSERT INTO test (text1 , text2)
SELECT CODE,NAME FROM CTE_TEST
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

You can use your additional logic inside the CTE, and simply insert the result set to actual table. Here the insert statement is outside the loop (1 insert statement with 3000000 records) , so it will faster than inserting the record inside a loop 3000000 times (3000000 insert statements with 1 record each)

By default the MAXRECURSION is 100 to avoid infinite looping, here you need to override this (but it is not a good practice).

Comment: Please post an explanation of why this code would be faster.

Comment: Here the insert statement is outside the loop (1 insert statement with 3000000  records) , so it will faster than inserting the record inside a loop 3000000 times (3000000 insert statements with 1 record each).

Comment: Unless he has changed the recursion limit on his server, won't this will fail after 100 records?  And raising the limit high enough to allow 3000000 records is probably not advisable.

Comment: Abdul Rasheed: It fails after 100 records.

Comment: This is using a recursive to count which is still RBAR. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/ A much better approach would be to use a numbers or tally table.

Comment: @vj78 edited the result. By default the MAXRECURSION is 100 to avoid infinite looping, here you need to override this (but it is not a good practice).

Comment: @Abdul Rasheed - I tried your approach in a different manner. Along with Rahul approach of batch. I inserted 9 million rows in 37 secs compared to 3 million rows in 3.5 hours

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that does not use recursive CTE is to use a known table with many enough records, so that you can iterate against it:

```
-- generation parameters
declare @batchCount INT = 100000
declare @totalCount INT = 30000000
declare @loopCount INT = @totalCount / @batchCount

DECLARE @i as int = 0
-- loops are slow, but here we have only a few
WHILE (@i < @loopCount)
BEGIN
    -- insert can be put just here to actually perform the insert
    -- ROW_NUMBER gives us the numbering, but order does not matter, so using SELECT 1
    select TOP (@batchCount) N'你好','VJ'+ cast(@i * @batchCount + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as varchar(20))
    from sys.messages

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

`sys.messages` is a pretty large table (at least `200K` records), so it can safely be used for batches of `100K`.

Time using `recursive CTE`: 51s

Time using above solution: 28s

(tested on a `SQL Server 2014 Express` instance, `SELECT` only)

Comment: I did not use recursive approach or loop
 
but instead used CTE with 3 batch select statements with union all to create CTE 

then inserted into new table from CTE

Comment: I tried this on my system exactly like you have and added insert statement its taking more than 5 minutes.