# How can I insert millions of rows of data with a loop (in a pre-made H2 table)?

Tags: sql, h2

I have the following table in my database and would like to populate it with a lot of data to test the performance of certain queries.

```
create table component_schedule (
component_schedule_id bigint generated by default as identity,
component_id bigint not null,
component_schedule_start_time timestamp not null,
component_schedule_end_time timestamp not null,
component_available_then boolean not null,
primary key (component_schedule_id));
```

I'm having trouble making a loop that will insert a few million rows of data. Help ?

Comment: What is the need for the loop? Can we have a little more context of what you are trying to do other than just loading millions of records into a table?

Comment: I just figured you need some sort of loop if you want to load that many records, I don't know for certain that it's necessary. Basically once I have all those records in there, I want to see how long general (and specific) `SELECT` and `UPDATE` commands take. The data in each records doesn't matter too much, just needs to fit the data type of the associated column.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need a loop to insert data into a table unless there are specific reasons that you need to interrogate each individual row which doesn't seem to be the case.

You can do a simple insert into statement to accomplish what you are seeking to do. You can reference this tutorial if you don't know how to... https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: The tutorial doesn't really say how to insert many times, it just says how to insert.

Comment: Please see the accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035738/sql-server-insert-statement-with-loop-needs-optimized for a better way of doing this.   The answer shows how to insert a set of numbers quickly into a temp table and then use that temp table to quickly insert data into the destination table.